# How to I find out which package includes a certain stack/nodes on ubuntu

Tags: ros, ubuntu, stack, package, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ros on my Ubuntu system via the ppa
Now I need some more stacks/nodes which are included within some packages.
Example:
How to I find out that the ros-fuerte-camera_umd package includes the uvc_camera node.

Greetings
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34643/how-to-i-find-out-which-package-includes-a-certain-stack/nodes-on-ubuntu/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2012-05-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-23**:
Warning: stack names have underscores, but the corresponding Debian package names substitute dashes. So, it's really `ros-fuerte-camera-umd`.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-23**:
Note that not all stacks/packages have debs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The debs should be named ros--
What I do is:

1. Find the package in the wiki. In the navigation bar you usually can find out the stack is named STACK.
2. Look for ros-fuerte-STACK.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1